# Is there a way to suppress ssh `user logged in` text, through fabric?

Tags: python, regex, ssh

The problem I have is that I issue several commands to remote machines through fabric, and read their response into a corresponding array. However, if the remote system issues the typical `Enter password: User <user> logged in.` text, it's included with my output and thus throws off the check for successful output.

I guess alternatively, is there an easy regex that could strip out the first bit of text?

Example output:

`Enter password: User DOMAIN/un logged in. +--+|1|+--+|1|+--+`

The only important part being `+--+|1|+--+|1|+--+` ..

Comment: Your examples really don't help. Do a sub string replace `Enter password: User DOMAIN/un logged in. ` with nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[\w\s\/:.]+
```

Try this.Use re.sub to replace this with `empty string`.

```
y=re.sub(r"^[\w\s\/:.]+","",x)
```

`x` being your string.`y` us your answer.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/27

Comment: Hey thanks for this - unfortunately, my DOMAIN has a hyphen `-` -- so it's actually closer to like `MY-DOMAIN/un`. How can I modify your regex to check for that?

Comment: @MrDuk use `^[\w\s\/:.-]+`